# Is there a more efficient way to work with a binary file?

Tags: php

I have a script that does a whole bunch of `fread` and `fseek` calls on a binary file, using a file pointer created like this:

```
$fp = fopen('r','mybinaryfile');
```

The script deals with around 2,500 separate files within the binary, each of which attracts a number of `fseek` and `fread` calls, so total operations on the file pointer probably well exceeds 20,000.

Am I right in thinking that each of these calls using my `$fp` file pointer results in a physical read action on the disk?

If so, I'm wondering if it would be better to load the whole file into memory and work with it like that. Would it?

Currently when I run this script, it takes around 20 seconds. Seems to me like there is room for improvement.

EDIT: And also, if it is possible to bring the file into memory, how is that achieved, while sticking with the pointer approach? The files are only around 3MB each, so running out of memory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It would be faster to load the whole thing into memory as long as you have enough memory for it to fit, otherwise it's a bit iffy. All in all though, 20 seconds is no biggy as long as you don't need to run it every minute.

Comment: I guess also my question is how to load it into memory heh... but thanks for answering. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that each of these calls using my $fp file
>   pointer results in a physical read action on the disk?

No, not necessarily.  The OS will buffer the file into memory so the reads and writes don't have to hit the disk immediately.  OS'es are quite good at doing this as well.

Here is a way to read the whole file into memory and still be able to operate on it using file streams.

```
$content = file_get_contents('large_file.bin');
$membuf = fopen("php://memory", "w+b");
fputs($membuf, $content);
unset($content);
rewind($membuf);

// now you can read and seek on $membuf using the usual stream functions fseek, fread etc
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. It didn't really speed things up at all though, so I guess you're right about the OS buffering!

Answer (score 0):

Store the whole file in memory by reading it into a variable as a string or array. Do whatever you want on it, then write it back. The only problem is, someone else may edit the file while your PHP script is working in memory, so you might want to lock the file after you read it, and unlock before you write.

Answer (score 0):

Loading your binary into the memory should be preferable if you are doing a lot of stuff on the file (not just one shot operation), as long as you have enough memory to contain your file.

In PHP, to load a file into memory, you can use `file_get_contents`

`file_get_contents` http://php.net/file_get_contents

```
$content = file_get_contents('mybinaryfile');

// $content is a string containing the whole content of your binary
```

You can then "point" to anywhere on the file using array reference,

```
$content[100]; // the 101th character of your binary
```

When you are done, to write it back, use `file_put_contents` http://php.net/file_put_contents

```
file_put_contents('mybinaryfile', $content);
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `file` on a binary file.